# How we can calculate the value of Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How we can calculate the value of Datagridview cell like if cell value is 6+2+9 and result is shown in second column
Column A Column B
6+6+2 ???
**i tried this code but second cell not show result of first cell**

```
    Dim DocNo As String
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
       Try
          DocNo = 
 Math.Abs(CDbl(DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString))
          DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = DocNo
      Catch
         DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = "?"
      End Try
   End If
```

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour].

Comment: You can use the [DataTable.Compute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute) method. Simpler to use in case the DataSource of your DGV is already a DataTable. But you can generate a DataTable object (you can use a Field to store it) to calculate an expression when a Cell value changes.